# Putting coordinate location markers in an SVG

Tags: svg

I'd like to create a list of locations markers on an svg graphic that I can call upon, using the id, to place content at dynamically.

what is the best way of achieving this?

I'm thinking of using an empty def like this:

```
<defs>
   <g id="coord"></g>
</defs>       

<use xlink:href="#coord" id="L1" x="10" y="10" />  
<use xlink:href="#coord" id="L2" x="100" y="100" />
```

Is there another way of doing this?
Is there any visual editor that can be used to generate `use` elements and assign ids?

Comment: "Is there any visual editor that can be used to generate use elements[…]?" Yes, [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simpler approach would be to use something like:

```
<circle id="L1" cx="10" cy="10" r="0" />
```

Without a radius (and assuming there is no stroke-width in effect), they won't be visible.

And if you put them in their own group or layer in your Inkscape file, you can temporarily give them all a stroke-width or non-zero radius if you want to edit them.  Then reset them back when you save the final version.

Comment: would it be possible to do this with a textfield? I'm thinking that if the coordinate ids were visible, it would be more intuitive to use

Comment: You mean something like `<text id="L1" x="10" y+"10" font-size="0"/>L1</text>`?  I don't see why not.